# Importing csv rows to powershell, with date specified as greater than

Tags: powershell, csv, date, import, conditional-statements

I have two csv files. One with a report from AD, containing accounts created during last month, second is manually kept database, that should theoretically contain the same information, but from all history of our company, with some additional data needed for accounting. I imported the AD report to powershell, now I need to import specific rows of the database. The rows I need are defined by a value in column "Date added". I need to import only rows, where the date exceeds specific value. I have this code:

```
$Report = Read-Host "File name" #AD report, last ten chars are date of report creation, in format yyyy-MM-dd 
$Date_text = $Report.Substring($Report.get_Length()-10)
$Date = Get-Date -Date $Date_text
$Date_limit = (($Date).AddDays(-$Date.Day)).Date
$Date_start = $Date_limit.AddMonths(-1)
$CSVlicence = Import-Csv $Database -Encoding UTF8 | 
where {(Where-Object {![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.'Date added')} |
ForEach-Object{$_.'Date added' = $_.'datum Pridani' -as [datetime] $_}) -gt $Date_start}
```

When run like this, nothing is imported. Without the condition the database is imported successfully, but it's extremely large and the rest of the script takes for ever. So I need to work only with relevant data. I don't care, that when Date_limit is 30th Sep, the Date_start would be 30th Aug instead of 31st Aug. That's just few more rows, but all those 10 years or so really takes for ever, if everything is imported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on your current logic, it filters the `PSCustomObject` based on your constraints, which is the wrong way to handle it since any item in the object will cause it to be filtered out.  You want to filter the source.

```
$Report = Read-Host -Prompt 'Filename'
## Grabs the datestamp at the end
$Date = Get-Date -Date $Report.Substring($Report.Length - 10)
## Grabs last day of previous month
$Limit = $Date.AddDays(-$Date.Day)
## Grabs last day of two months ago, inaccuracy of one day
$Start = $Limit.AddMonths(-1)

Get-Content -Path $Database -TotalCount 1 | Set-Content -Path 'tempfile'
Get-Content -Path $Database -Encoding 'UTF8' |
    ## Checks that the entry has a valid date entry within limits
    ForEach-Object {
      ## For m/d/yy or d/m/yy variants, try
      ## '\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2,4}'
      If ($_ -match '\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}')
      {
        [DateTime]$Date = $Matches[0]
        If ($Date -gt $Start -and $Date -lt $Limit) { $_ }
      }
    } |
    Add-Content -Path 'tempfile'

$CSV = Import-Csv -Path 'tempfile' -Encoding 'UTF8'
```

Comment: @EBGreen I realized an issue with my interpretation of the problem.  I'm updating it

Comment: I forgot to mention, that the date format in the "Date added" column is M/d/yyyy, not as in the report file name. So I changed the operand after -match to '\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}'. I tried even '\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}', but I encountered a problem. After running the script, I get message "cmdlet ForEach-Object at command pipeline position 2 Supply values for the following parameters: Process[0]: I have no idea what to put there.

Comment: @PetrSynek You moved the brace to its own line so it doesn't know where its scriptblock is.

Comment: I moved the { just after the cmdlet on the same line (strange, I always put it on a new line and never had any problems so far) and the prompt is no longer displayed. But still no data is imported. I wonder if the '\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}' operand must be changed somehow.

Comment: @PetrSynek `ForEach-Object` is a cmdlet and the parser can't magically know its arguments are on the next line.  As to your match not working, try this: `'\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2,4}'`  This will catch all variants of a m/d/yy datestamp.

Comment: I discovered the problem might be elsewhere. In fact, I don't use the $Database variable directly. I use a custom function to define the file. It worked well with the Import-Csv cmdlet, but perhaps Get-Content might have problem with it? Specifically, my code now looks like this: `Get-Content -Path (ConvertExcelPridani -File $Licence) -TotalCount 1 | Set-Content -Path 'tempfile'`. Same with the other Get-Content cmdlet.

Comment: @PetrSynek Which version of PowerShell?  IIRC, `-TotalCount` wasn't introduced until v3.

Comment: PS v 5.1 I updated it as soon as I entered the company. So this won't be the problem

Comment: Oh, my bad, I got it now, I made a syntax error in the script code :-( Works now. I wrote [DateTme] instead of [DateTime]. Sorry for that

Comment: @PetrSynek Great, if it resolves your problem, please mark it as an answer for future googlers